# iphone - How to call a function every time a tab is changed?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller

I am an iOS development newbie. I have a tab bar controller with an array of navigation controllers. I want a method to be called that invokes a webservice every time one of the tabs is clicked. I know I could assign a selector to a delegate for this purpose. I am just not sure about the syntax. Is this the right way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to refer to UITabBarControllerDelegate Protocol Reference.

You can use [tabBarController:didSelectViewController:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006932-CH3-SW1)  delegate method.

Hope this helps.